# Fontawesome with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, font-awesome

I've used some dependencies in build.gradle.kts (Module:app) but not working

I've used com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView and this is the problem:
Class referenced in the layout file, com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView, was not found in the project or the libraries
And the project is sync with gradle files

Comment: share your build gradle code